# C# equivalent of Java's List<? extends MyFancyClass>

Tags: c#, generics

I don't believe I saw this anywhere (I'm not sure how to word the question really so that may be why) so if it's already been answered I apologise.

I'm currently writing an application that has an event API that third parties can hook into, below is the code I'm using to fire the events.

```
// Events.cs from the API project
public interface IEventListener
{
    void Handle(IEvent @event);
}

public abstract class EventManager
{
    public abstract void Register(PluginBase plugin, IEventListener listener);
    public abstract void Call(IEvent @event);
}

// Events.cs from the main project
public class SimpleEventManager : EventManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<PluginBase, List<IEventListener>> _events = 
        new Dictionary<PluginBase, List<IEventListener>>();

    public override void Register(PluginBase plugin, IEventListener listener)
    {

    }

    public override void Call(IEvent @event)
    {
       // Iterate through _events.Values and call Handle on each IEventListener
    }
}
```

Whilst the code above works fine I find how third parties hook into it to be incredibly ugly and was wondering if it would be possible to hook it up to use the `Action` class.

```
// TestPlugin.cs
class MyTestPlugin : PluginBase
{
    var handler = new MyEventHandler();
    App.Instance.EventManager.Register(this, handler);
}

class MyEventHandler : IEventListener
{
   public void Handle(IEvent @event)
   {
       if(@event is SomeEvent) HandleSomeEvent((SomeEvent) @event);
   }

   private void HandleSomeEvent(SomeEvent someEvent)
   {
       // Handle the event of course
   }
}
```

My goal is to change the Register method to accept a third parameter, `Action<IEvent>` though I've found out that if I reference a method then it must strictly accept an IEvent as an argument. In Java you can use `<? extends BaseClass>` (self explanatory), is there something like `Action<? : IEvent>` or is this simply not possible?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx ?

Comment: @dbarnes how would I store this in a List though? I tried `List<Action<IEvent>>` for the sake of it and as expected there was an error reading "cannot convert from '`System.Action<T>`' to '`System.Action<Flatpack.API.Events.IEvent>`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is called "generic constraints".  You'd express it like this:

```
public interface IEventListener<TEvent> where TEvent: IEvent
{
    void Handle(TEvent @event);
}

class MyEventHandler : IEventListener<SomeEvent>
{
   public void Handle(SomeEvent @event)
   {
       // Handle the event of course
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, only problem is I'm not quite sure how to store it in the Dictionary I have!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but one potential solution is to have both a generic and non-generic `IEventListener`.  (just like how `IEnumerable` works)

That way you can use the non-generic as the type for your dictionary.